# Can you add to an array in Ruby whose name is dependent upon a variable?

Tags: ruby, arrays, string, variables

Let's suppose a store owner wants to know how well his products are selling around the world, and which are selling best where.

He has the following data: |ID,Currency,Quantity,Location|

Rather than iterate through the data for each currency (data set > 10,000), is there a way to put the data into arrays specific to the currency without explicit designation...i.e., is there a way to avoid

```
if curr == "USD"; USDid << ID; USDquan << Quantity
elsif...
```

...and so on?  For the purposes of this question, assume the *id and *quan arrays exist for the currencies under observation.

Is there some sort of regex trick that can look at the currency and put the data in the appropriate arrays?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. Use a hash of arrays instead of multiple arrays:

```
sale_data = {}
sale_data.default = {"ID" => [], "Quantity" => [], "Location" => []}
# Later...
sale_data[curr]["ID"] << ID; sale_data[curr]["Quantity"] << quan; #Etc..
```

The `default=` call makes it so you can just assign as many currencies as you want without every predefining them. So, anywhere in your code, if there are not prior entries for, say, USD, when you add data, one is created.